# Ethernet connection for Realtek RTL8139/810x not working

Tags: connection, realtek, ethernet

I installed ubuntu recently and i cant connect to internet....
I never deal with linux before much but i cant connect to internet and it keeps giving notification wired connection disconnected

Its working fine on my windows 7
using Realtek RTL8139/810x ethernet network card

my isp need login on its webpage for connection of internet which i gets automatically after connection to lan but nothing is working on my ubuntu os....

please help me for this case.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was my mistake that I didn't set IP's required for connections

Answer (score 1):

I believe your kernel is loading the wrong driver. This has been experienced by others before and you need to run a script (a patch by a fellow linux user) to solve it. I believe the script blacklists the default driver and loads the correct one. You can find the script at https://gist.github.com/2390823. Download, extract and execute the script as root.

This information was found at http://kopiteforlife.wordpress.com/2012/05/01/recovering-from-ubuntu-12-04-lts-upgrade-failure-from-11-10/

Answer (score 0):

one of the main reasons for this PCI card not loading is the driver .
I just had this issue a few moments ago , and the way i solve it was by installing this driver :
https://gist.github.com/ttp/2390823

I also removed the card from PCI slot and put it there again just in case any bad contact was happening .